# React Router with Loadable Components error

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, react-router-v4, webpack-4, code-splitting

I've created a repository with a basic example that triggers this error in case it helps:

[loadable-components-ssr](https://github.com/amalv/loadable-components-ssr)

I'm trying to use Loadable Components in a SSR set up with `react-router-dom` `4.3.1`, `loadable-component` `5.6.0` and `react-dom` `16.8.1`

Here is a component example to which I'm trying to apply `loadable-component`:

```
import React from "react";

const About = () => <h2>About</h2>;

export default About;
```

This is imported in the `App` component like this:

```
import loadable from "@loadable/component";
...
const About = loadable(() => import("./About"));
```

And passed as a prop to `Route` in the same `App` component:

```
<Route path="/about/" component={About} />
```

But I keep getting the following warning in the Developer Tools console:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `component` of type `object` supplied to `Route`, expected `function`

If I use an alternative syntax as suggested in the [first answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54667771/722983):

```
<Route path="/about/" component={props => <About {...props} />} />
```

The warning disappears, but the route to `/about` still gives an error when the link is clicked:

```
Uncaught Error: Loading chunk About failed.
(missing: http://localhost:3000/about/About.bundle.js)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptComplete (VM1805 app.bundle.js:114)
```

I followed the [documentation](https://www.smooth-code.com/open-source/loadable-components/docs/server-side-rendering/) about setting up `loadable-components` in SSR, so I've set up the client, the server and also the babel plugin as indicated.

Any idea what's wrong here?

Comment: May be a issue with react router, try:
<Route path="/about/" exact component={props => <About {...props} /> } />

Comment: That fixes the warning, but unfortunately doing this still generates an error loading the `About` component when going to the route (in this case `/about`):

`loadable.es.js:246 Uncaught Error: Loading chunk About failed.`

Comment: Could you solve this? I'm getting the same error

Comment: Unfortunately I did not, may be I'll provide a link to a repository in order to reproduce the problem so it's easier to know what's wrong.

Comment: I think it should be okay in client-side render.The errors maybe happen as you don't config correctly for the ssr.

Answer (score 4):

This is a [known issue of react router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6420).

I think that you could code the route like this:

```
<Route path="/about/" component={props => <About {...props} />} />
```

Be careful with this implementation, because you could have some buggy behaviours with the re-renders.

Comment: That fixes the warning but the route (in this example `/about`), still does not work when using this syntax.

Comment: @rfc1484 have you tried to return the default import? `import(“./About”).then(c => c.default)`

Comment: Same error is returned: `Loading chunk About failed.`

Answer (score 1):

this is your "About" component:

```
import React from "react";

const About = () => <h2>About</h2>;

export default About;
```

you are not returning jsx. thats why you are getting error.
this is how you should have returned jsx.

```
 const About = () => (<h2>About</h2>);
```

cheers!

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use [react.lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html)? It is the official component.

```
const About = React.lazy(() => import('./About')
<Route exact path="/about" component={props => <About {...props} />} />
```

Comment: React lazy does not support server side rendering at the moment: `React.lazy and Suspense is not yet available for server-side rendering. If you want to do code-splitting in a server rendered app, we recommend Loadable Components. It has a nice guide for bundle splitting with server-side rendering.` 

https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html